# RobotFrameWork: Should be equal as Strings to use regular expressions

Tags: robotframework

So I have two possible valid values for `Should Be Equal As Strings`.

Is there a way to do something like

```
Should Be Equal As Strings  
...  Create  create|update
```

Doesn't necessarily need to be using that specific keyword but I want to be able to accept one of the other

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Should match regexp](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Should%20Match%20Regexp)

Here's an example:

```
*** Variables ***
${action1}   create
${action2}   update
${action3}   delete

*** Test Cases ***
Example
    Should match regexp  ${action1}  create|update
    Should match regexp  ${action2}  create|update
    Run keyword and expect error   'delete' does not match 'create|update'
    ...   Should match regexp  ${action3}  create|update
```

Comment: As the goal is a full match - e.g. "Should Be Equal As Strings", perhaps the regexp should be with start-end strings - something like `^(create|update)$`, following your example? Otherwise the check will pass with a string like "this is create".